# Cat Squinting Left Eye

Tags: cats, health

My cat hasn't changed it's behaviour at all but is squinting his left eye. He has done this before and it was just some sort of thing that like 15% of cats get. They gave him eye drops and he was fine. Now he is squinting again and his left eye is watering quite a bit. Should I take him to the vet? We have some eye drops from last time. Should I use those?

For those of you who wanted to know, he has now healed up. It was just a simple infection. Thats why I was hesitant to bother the vet, because we had some eye drops from when he had that last time. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would. It might be nothing, but it could be a  serious infection.

Comment: Go to a vet....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you should. An experienced veterinarian will be able to tell you whether it is infection of the sclera or conjunctiva (bacterial and/or viral), cataracts, glaucoma (very serious!), injuries with corneal ulceration, allergies, chemical irritation, something stuck in the eye or nerve damage.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, go to the vet.  It could be an infection (as mentioned in comments) or it could be something else.  A hands on assessment by a trained professional is the best choice in your situation.